# I need to export a list of all users on our domain and I am not familiar with DSQUERY or DSGET?

Tags: active-directory, dsquery

I am really struggling to create the query that will export the following:
Account
FirstName
LastName
the OU that the user resides in

Ideally I would like it as a CSV.  I do not have access to the domain controller, but can run DSQUERY/DSGET/etc. from my pc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your tools, you can do

```
dsquery user dc=contoso,dc=com | dsget user -samid -fn -ln -dn > names.csv
```

That'll create a space-separated list of account name, firstname, lastname, and location.

Converting it into a true csv takes a bit more work.

```
$userList=dsquery user dc=contoso,dc=com | dsget user -samid -fn -ln -dn
foreach ($user in $userList) {
    $outstring=$user.trim(" ") -replace('\s+',',')
    write-host  `"$outstring`"
}
```

Which will get you output like

```
"samid","fn","ln","dn"
"jarey.boe","jarey","boe","cn=jarey.boe,ou=users,dc=contoso,dc=com"
```

Comment: What does the dc=contoso mean?

Comment: @Neil It's part of the full Distinguished Name for the object. The `dc` bits are the DNS names for your AD domain-name.

Comment: If i can high 5 who provided the powerscript, i would. Your amazing and a life saver!

Answer (score 6):

dsquery works but the conversion to CSV by splitting on one or more spaces (\s+ ) is tenuous. Any attribute value with embedded spaces is going to shift the remaining values to the right. Also, by default dsquery will stop after outputting 100 objects; "-limit 0" will output all results.

The correct way to do this via command line is using csvde:

```
csvde -f names.csv -r "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user))" -l samAccountName,givenName,sn
```

The obligatory PowerShell method is:

```powershell
$a = [adsisearcher]'(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user))'
$a.PageSize = 1000
$a.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@('samAccountName','givenName','sn','distinguishedName'))
$a.FindAll() | ForEach-Object {
    $b = $_.properties
    $op = '' | select DN,sAMAccountName,sn,givenName
    $op.DN = $b.distinguishedname[0]
    if ($b.samaccountname) { $op.samAccountName = $b.samaccountname[0] }
    if ($b.givenname) { $op.givenName = $b.givenname[0] }
    if ($b.sn) { $op.sn = $b.sn[0] }
    $op
} | Export-Csv names3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```